# In Eclipse, what plugin/class provides the style formatting on Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting

As you type Java code in Eclipse, the Viewer colors, emboldens, italicizes, fades, and provides styles to the Java code as you type it, as seen in the picture:

[image: Eclipse Formatting]

What is actually implementing these effects?

Is it an Eclipse plugin? Can you identify which (and tell me how you identified it)? Furthermore can you narrow it down to a class?

Answer (score 2):

Select "Peferences" from the Eclipse menu.
Go to Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Preferences can be set at project level.

Incase you are planning on writing your own formatting code, then take a look at "workspace mechanics" plugin.

Comment: Where do I find that plugin?

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/ update site is listed under the "Access" section and there are links at the bottom of the page on getting started and configuring it.

Comment: @dominatorX Formatter handles formatting, no?  OP appears to be wanting to know about the syntax fonts and coloring, not code formatting.

Comment: For coloring from Eclipse menu Preferences/General/Appearence/Colors and Fonts

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use Eclipse's formatting when I present the code in my own viewer to my own specifications. I'd like it to appear the way Eclipse would represent it.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is part of the JDT project (Java Developer Tools). The actual code sits in org.eclipse.jdt.core (non-UI parts) and org.eclipse.jdt.ui (UI parts).

The viewer stuff is mostly in the UI plugin ([sources](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui)). It's hard to give any more specifics as highlighting includes custom viewer, parser, extension mechanisms (for 3rd party plugins)